# Finding the "noise level" of an audio recording programmatically

Tags: audio

I am tasked with something seemingly trivial which is to
find out how "noisy" a given recording is.

This recording came about via a voice recorder, a
OLYMPUS VN-733 PC which was fairly cheap (I am not doing
advertisement, I merely mention this because I in no way
aim to do anything "professional" here, I simply need to
solve a seemingly simple problem).

To preface this, I have already obtained several datasets
from different outside locations, in particular parks or 
near-road recordings. That is, the noise that exists at
these specific locations, and to then compare this noise,
on average, with the other locations.

In other words:

I must find out how noisy location A is compared to location
B and C.

I have made 1 minute recordings each so that at the
least the time span of a recording can be compared
to the other locations (and I was using the very 
same voice record at all positions, in the same
height etc...).

A sample file can be found at:

http://shevegen.square7.ch/test.mp3

(This may eventually be moved lateron, it just serves as
example how these recordings may sound right now. I am
unhappy about the initial noisy clipping-sound, ideally
I'd only capture the background noise of the cars etc..
but for now this must suffice.)

Now my specific question is, how can I find out how "noisy"
or "loud" this is?

The primary goal is to compare them to the other .mp3
files, which would suffice for my purpose just fine.

But ideally it would be nice to calculate on average
how "loud" every individual .mp3 is and then compared
it to the other ones (there are several recordings
per given geolocation, so I could even merge them
together).

There are some similar questions but not one in particular
that I was able to find that could answer this in a 
objective manner, or perhaps I did not understand the 
problem at hand. I have all the audio datasets already
but I have no idea how to find out how "loud" any one
of them is individually; there are some apps on smartphones
that claim that they can do this automatically but since
I do not have any smartphone, this is a dead end for me.

Any general advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Question probably belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com, since it's more about audio and DSP theory than programming *per se*. Note that if you are going to measure noise levels "properly" you'll want to consider applying one of the standard weighting curves, e.g. [A weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-weighting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noise is a notion difficult to define. Then, I will focus on loudness.

You could compute the energy of each files. For that, you need to access the samples of the audio signal (generally from a built-in function of you programming language). Then you could compute the RMS energy of the signal.

That could be the more basic processing.